# how to use a specific int variable in more than one class

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a game class sub class of CCLayer where i declare a int variable gameScore in .h file and initialize/update this variable in .m class.Now I need show this gameScore value in another class when game is over.But i don't know how to do it.Infact i found severarl solution but most of them didn't work for me or i can't understand them properly.So i need a simple example of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a singleton class for storing you game data. Look here http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also "cheat" and use the NSUserDefaults database. See here http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/20/using_nsuserdefaults/

Please note that this is only a "good cheat" if you have a couple variables that you need to access. If you have a feeling that your program might get more complex in the future, invest an hour in making your own singleton - it's really worth it.